# how can i plot an excel file in real time by Matlab

Tags: excel, database, real-time

I have an Excel DATA which I want to plot in matlab. on same plot I want to plot a real time data. Can anyone suggest a method to do it.
Regards Omar

I tried to do an algorithm who call the data (excel file) and I'm trying to do a loop to get the real-time plotting

Comment: So get Excel to save as csv, then Matlab reads the csv.